# Weighted Mean Before or After Linear Fitting?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

When given multiple sets (corresponding to multiple trials in an experiment) of coordinates with their associated ordinate uncertainties, with the goal of linearly fitting the data being to find the slope, is it better to take the weighted means of the y-values before linearly fitting these mean values to the x-values, or to first take a linear fit for each trial and to take the weighted mean of the slopes?

Comment: Why are you weighting the means?  Indeed, why are you using means at all rather than simply using all the observations together?

Comment: Initially, I figured that weighted means were the best way to combine data from different trials. But would it be just as fitting (mind the pun) to have only one linear fit where the data from all the trials are used?

Comment: How would you weight the slopes? Using $R^2$ values? Using mean y values before fitting is a good idea because it eliminates outliers, which have significantly more weight in least-squares fitting. Unless you are weighting by squared distances.